# Regarding the solution of finding the remainder of $g(x^{12})$ divided by $g(x)$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Let $g(x) = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1.$ What is the remainder when the polynomial $g(x^{12})$ is divided by the polynomial $g(x)$?

I'm reading the solution for this and I don't understand how can someone come up with it.

It states

> We have that $g(x^{12}) = x^{60} + x^{48} + x^{36} + x^{24} + x^{12} + 1$

which is still very clear. Then it goes to say that

> Note that $(x - 1)g(x) = (x - 1)(x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) = x^6 - 1$

but I am not "noting" this. Where is this expression coming form? There is nothing natural to it.

Furhtermore they state that

> Also,
> \begin{align*}
> g(x^{12}) - 6 &= (x^{60} + x^{48} + x^{36} + x^{24} + x^{12} + 1) - 6 \\
> &= (x^{60} - 1) + (x^{48} - 1) + (x^{36} - 1) + (x^{24} - 1) + (x^{12} - 1).
> \end{align*}

which is also not very natural to come up with. Where is this $6$ coming from?

The rest follows from $g(x^{12})-6$ being a multiple of $g$ and the remainder is thusfore $6$. I hate reading these kinds of solutions there is nothing to be learnt from this. It's just a bunch of sentences with not substance to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confess i was, am, and will be also hating "artificial" solutions for problems that hide the structure. As a college student, many competitions i took part at had problems that were easily solved with the *knowledge* of structure, that would have come next year, but which were on a thin path also doable by the "poor man's artillery" from the present knowledge. People having roughly the knowledge from the next year's structural path had a much better chance...

OK, to the given problem. I will avoid the artificial way of addressing the problem, and use the more or less structural way. The key-word is (maybe) "cyclotomic polynomial" and/or "unit roots".

Yes, $$f=f(x)=x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$ has roots, that are all roots of the unit of order (dividing) six. The identity
$$
(x-1)\cdot f=(x-1)(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x^6-1)
$$
confirms this.
For later use, i will denote by $x_1=\zeta=\frac 12(1+i\sqrt 3)$, $x_2=\zeta^2=\frac 12(-1+i\sqrt 3)$, $x_3=\zeta^3=-1$,
$x_4=\zeta^4=\bar x_2=\frac 12(-1-i\sqrt 3)$,
$x_5=\zeta^5=\bar x_1=\frac 12(1-i\sqrt 3)$ the five roots of $f$.

So let us do the job without the "trick", but using the knowledge of the roots.
We are searching for an identity of the shape
$$
f(x^{12}) = f(x)\cdot q(x)+r(x)\ ,
$$
and we do not need the quotient $q$ obtained by dividing with rest $f(x^{12})$ by $f(x)$, only the rest $r$, uniquely determined by the above relation and by the condition of having degree $<5$. So $r(x) = r_0+r_1x+r_2x^2+r_3x^3+r_4x^4$, and we need the coefficients of $r$.

Now we simply plug in the five roots into this equation. Note that $x_k^6=1$ for all indices $k$ from one to five. So $f(x_k^{12})=f(1)=1+1+1+1+1+1=6$.

(This is the first point where one can clearly see $r=6$, a constant, since it satisfies the two needed conditions. But to conclude in similar cases, without seeing the evidence...)

Then $f(x_k)=0$ for these indices $k$, since we plug in a root. This leads to (the linear system):
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
6 &= f(x_1^{12})
=f(x_1)\cdot q(x_1)+r(x_1) 
= r(x_1)=r_0+r_1x_1+r_2x_1^2+r_3x_1^3+r_4x_1^4
\\
6 &= f(x_2^{12})
=f(x_2)\cdot q(x_2)+r(x_2) 
= r(x_2)=r_0+r_1x_2+r_2x_2^2+r_3x_2^3+r_4x_2^4
\\
6 &= f(x_3^{12})
=f(x_3)\cdot q(x_3)+r(x_3) 
= r(x_3)=r_0+r_1x_3+r_2x_3^2+r_3x_3^3+r_4x_3^4
\\
6 &= f(x_4^{12})
=f(x_4)\cdot q(x_4)+r(x_4) 
= r(x_4)=r_0+r_1x_4+r_2x_4^2+r_3x_4^3+r_4x_4^4
\\
6 &= f(x_5^{12})
=f(x_5)\cdot q(x_5)+r(x_5) 
= r(x_5)=r_0+r_1x_5+r_2x_5^2+r_3x_5^3+r_4x_5^4
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
In other words, written in matrix form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6\\6\\6\\6\\6
\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & x_1^4\\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & x_2^3 & x_2^4\\
1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & x_3^3 & x_3^4\\
1 & x_4 & x_4^2 & x_4^3 & x_4^4\\
1 & x_5 & x_5^2 & x_5^3 & x_5^4\\
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\text{Vandermonde matrix}}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_0\\r_1\\r_2\\r_3\\r_4
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Of course, the column of six-values is easily obtained from the column of one-values, so we "must see" the solution $r(x)=6$, i.e. $r_0=6$, $r_1=r_2=r_3=r_4=0$. This solution is unique, since the Vandermonde matrix has determinant not equal to zero.

---

And now, **knowing** the solution, "we" may want to type less in a book, since books are expensive, they must be condensed even if changed beyond recognition. So we may rearrange the story, ignore the "iterpolation step", and just show with dirty, artificial means that $f(x^{12})-6$ is divisible by $f(x)$. Of course, this is easily done:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x^{12})-6
&=
(x^{60}-1)+
(x^{48}-1)+
(x^{36}-1)+
(x^{24}-1)+
(x^{12}-1)+
(1-1)
\\
&=
(x^6-1)(x^{54}+\dots + x^6+1)
\\
&\qquad\qquad +(x^6-1)(x^{42}+\dots + x^6+1)
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad 
+(x^6-1)(x^{30}+\dots + x^6+1)
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+
(x^6-1)(x^{18}+ \dots + x^6+1)
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
(x^6-1)(x^6+1)
\\
&=(x^6-1)(\dots)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so it is a multiple of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

> $(x - 1)g(x) = (x - 1)(x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) = x^6 - 1$

That product is "telescoping":
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
(x - 1)(x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
&= &x^6 &+ x^5 &+ x^4 &+ x^3 &+ x^2 &+ x \\
&  &    &- x^5 &- x^4 &- x^3 &- x^2 &- x &-1 \\
&=& x^6&&&&&&-1
\end{array}$$
More generally: $$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$